# GetHomePath Delphi-xe5 Android open pdf

Tags: android, delphi, pdf, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to open a pdf in Android Device from an app developed in Delphi-XE5. My code is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  try
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI('/sdcard/android/data/db/Rad.pdf'),             StringToJString('application/pdf'));
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent)
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

But when i press the button, is showed the different apps for open a pdf document, I select any one of them, and all of them are open correctly, but they say that the document has not been able to open.

The paths is set correctly.

Any Advise

Comment: Please include the `delphi` tag to your delphi related questions

Comment: Maybe the document is not correct, check it first with something like http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx

Comment: As you told me, i have checked and it told me that is corrupt in some areas, but such pdf is oppening corectly without any problem with the Adobe Reader installed in the tablet. It is happening with all the pdf's files.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the file to another directory, "/sdcard/", for example.
The documentations says that folders in /sdcard/android/data/ are public and can be accessed from any app, but in reality it's not always true.